# Change Detection using Vector files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, classification, change-detection, ecognition

I have two shapefiles showing LULC of the same area for two different years; 1990 and 2015. Number of Polygons in two files are different but the number of class in both are same.

Is there any way to do the change detection study using these vector files?

I have ArcMap 10 and eCognition to use? Suggestion of any other tool is welcome.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please decide which of eCognition and ArcGIS Desktop you wish to ask about within this question so that it and its answers can be focussed on what you have tried and where you are stuck.